# jQuery load + Spring + Thymeleaf. Подгрузка файлов

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

Есть файл, допустим, `general.html`:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Этот файл я хочу "импортировать" в файл `index.html` с помощью `ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let trigger = $('.left-side > div > a'),
        container = $('.right-side');

    trigger.click(function () {
        let $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');

        container.load(target + '.txt');

        return false;
    });
});
```

В обычном браузере данный код у меня работает нормально, но когда дело доходит до spring, файл не может быть загружен, потому что он "недоступен" для использования.

Вопрос:
Как мне реализовать загрузку файла `general.html` в `index.html`, при этом запретить доступ юзерам к просмотру данного файла "напрямую" (допустим, www.example.com/includes/general.html)?

Comment: Что доступно JavaScript, то доступно браузеру. Так что запретить не получится.

Comment: Надо использовать структурированный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ум приходит такая идея:

1. Создайте сервис для получения файла.

   ```
   public interface FileService {
      File load(String path);
   }
   ```
2. Реализуйте его.

   ```
   @Service
   public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {
       @Override
       public File load(String path) {
           return new File(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString() + path);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Используйте напрямую в контроллере или как компонент другого сервиса.

   ```
   @RestController
   public class CssLoaderRestController {
   @Autowired
   private FileService fileService;

   @GetMapping(value = "/api/css")
   public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getCss(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name)
           throws IOException {

       File f = fileService.load("/css/" + name + ".css");

       return ResponseEntity
               .ok()
               .header("Content-Type", "text/css")
               .body(new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(f)));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: CSS файл меня не интересует)) Интересует загрузка кода

Comment: Ваш случай ещё проще: `@GetMapping(value = "/api/html")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getHtml() throws IOException {
        String data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("general.html")));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK); }` и сам запрос `$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/html',
                dataType: 'text',
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                success: function (data) {
                    document.body.innerHTML = data;
                }});`